# How do I connect my kitchen sink sprayer

Tags: kitchens, faucet, sink

I just bought a house, and the first thing to break is the spray hose for my kitchen sink.  It was added recently, and I'm unable to find any brand listed to help me understand the parts, or even what is broken.

[image: below view]
[image: quick connect]
[image: side view]
[image: hose]

<sub>Click for full size image</sub>

My problem is that the quick-connect adapter doesn't actually hold the end of the hose.  It falls right out and water sprays into the cabinet under the sink.

Comment: I am very interested in this post. Especially the closeup picture of the hose with the quick disconnect fitting. Can you tell me what manufacturer made your spray hose?? I have the same male fitting on my kitchen faucet. I will have to throw away the entire faucet which works fine just because I can't find the replacement hose for my leaky one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What it looks like is you shove the hose in, then pull the plastic clip outwards to lock it in. If water sprays out of it, you need new o-rings. If the hose shoots out, either that's not the clip, or some of the plastic is chipped making an unreliable lock.

If this isn't the case, could you tell us what you've done to try and fix it already and what moving parts you see? Perhaps a photo of the top of the faucet may help too

Comment: I think the same - pulling the plastic clip outwards to lock it, but it doesn't seem to move with the hose attached.  The hose shoots out, but it doesn't appear that any of the plastic is chipped.  I'll try messing with it some more and see if I can get it to work and will report back.

Comment: When you push the hose in, is it a tight fit?

Comment: Its relatively snug, but not snug enough that it stays when I turn on the water.

Comment: When you pull the plastic clip, how far does it move? Have you tried pulling the clip while pushing up on the hose at the same time?

Comment: How far in are you inserting the hose?  Until it "seats" itself?  See the 2 notches on both sides of the end of the hose?  The locking ring should fit into one of those (preferably the last one)  Try rotating the hose until the locking ring seats into the notch.

Comment: Hey, so I messed around with this a bit more.  The hose is in as far as it will go, but the quick connect will not lock no matter how I push, pull, tug, jimmy, etc.  I've got a temporary MacGyver, pulling the locking ring out with some shims and then duct-taping the whole thing together.  It seems to hold with no leaks, at least for the time being.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

That plastic clip that slides in and out to lock **should** have a small spring located on the outside between the tip of the clip and the housing. This holds tension on it and makes for a more positive lock. If that spring is gone it won't hold the hose.